# rdlc report with row, column grouping and subreport

Tags: c#, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am trying to create a rdlc report for student marks, the report gives all the exam marks for a year I have grouped the rows as per studentId, column grouping is made on examinationId. Each exam has child exams, I am using subreporting to fetch the child exams and the parameters passed are academic year, class, subject and parent exam id. I am able to get the report but the subreport gives an error(failed to load subreport data). The expected report is as in the image, any suggestion how to achieve?
[Image shows expected report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrAks.png)

Comment: It's going to be a bit tricky this one as we can't see the code and the error message is quite vague. I would suggest trying to split your problem up, comment/disable stuff and see if you can get something working....

Aside from that not too sure,

Comment: yes @RichardHousham its little tricky, I am half way though but more to be done.